# fix an Excel file with a corrupted sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a wookbook which has been corrupted after an bad Excel crash.

In the VB editor under the "Microsoft Excel Objects" there 2 workbook icons.

One is named "ThisWorkbook" and the other has a sheet name "Feuil15" (sheet 15 in french).

When I click on "Feuil15" the properties panel display the "ThisWorkbook" panel properties (even the name!). "Feuil15" has no code associated with, while  "ThisWorkbook" has the event handlers I have written.

I want to get rid of the "Feuil15" sheet but I can't delete it.

The workbook as plenty of code in sheets, ThisWorkbook plus froms, class modules and regular modules (240 files to load).
I do have some code to export the code but none to import the code from flat files.

did some has this issue and find a solution to solve it ?

Comment: if the only worksheet you have is a corrupt one and you want to remove it anyway, then just make a new workbook.

Comment: @Banana The workbook as plenty of code in sheets, ThisWorkbook plus class module and modules (240 files to load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to Drag and drop bas modules in the VB Editor to the exception of the *.frx files which are loaded automatically with *.frm files (form files). 
It is also possible to load class code files (*.cls). Sheet (also *.cls) and workbook code cannot be dragged and dropped. If macros are associated to shapes or objects layed on sheet surface they will be copied with the sheets but still point to the source file. All the macro should be reset manually. Also references in project options must be reset.